# How can I tab a QDockWidget by default

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm currently using QDockWidget controls in my PyQt4 application by docking them in the MainWindow. I dock them either to the left-hand side or the right-hand side, and I control where they are vertically by the order in which I add them. For example, if I want a QDockWidget docked on the right-hand side called "dockWindow1", and two dock windows on the left hand side called "dockWindow2" and "dockWindow3" with "dockWindow2" docked in the upper left-hand corner and "dockWindow3" in the lower left-hand corner, I do the following:

```
self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dockWindow1)
self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea,  dockWindow2)
self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea,  dockWindow3)
```

Now I'd like to add a new QDockWidget ("dockWindow4") to the upper-left hand docking area so that it appears tabbed with "dockWindow2". How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [tabifyDockWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#tabifyDockWidget).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!